# Jasmine.js Testing - spy on window.open

Tags: javascript, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

**JS**

```
var link = this.notificationDiv.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];

link.addEventListener('click', function (evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    visitDestination(next);
  }, false);
}

var visitDestination = function(next){
    window.open(next)
}
```

**Spec**

```
  var next = "http://www.example.com"

  it( 'should test window open event', function() {

    var spyEvent = spyOnEvent('#link', 'click' ).andCallFake(visitDestination(next));;
    $('#link')[0].click();
    expect( 'click' ).toHaveBeenTriggeredOn( '#link' );
    expect( spyEvent ).toHaveBeenTriggered();

    expect(window.open).toBeDefined();
    expect(window.open).toBe('http://www.example.com');    
 });
```

How to write the spec to test for when link is clicked it calls `visitDestination` and to ensures `window.open == next`? When I try to run the spec it opens the new window.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

So, `window.open` is a method provided by the browser. I don't believe it resets the value of itself. So this:

```
expect(window.open).toBe('http://www.example.com');
```

... is going to fail no matter what.

What you want is to create a mock of the window.open method:

```
spyOn(window, 'open')
```

This will allow you to track when it has been run. It will also prevent the actual `window.open` function from running. So a new window will not open when you run the test.

Next you should test that the `window.open` method was run:

```
expect(window.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith(next)
```

Edit: More detail. If you want to test that visitDestination has been run then you would do:

```
spyOn(window, 'visitDestination').and.callThrough()

...

expect(window.visitDestination).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

The `.and.callThrough()` is really important here. If you don't use it then the normal `visitDestination` will be replace with a dummy/mock function which does nothing.

Comment: I have added  - chai.spy.on(window, 'open') in 'beforeEach'. But still giving error 'Not implemented: window.open'. Can you please suggest solution for this?

Comment: Looks like whatever browser you're running in has not defined `window.open`. You can try `var mySpy = jasmine.createSpy('name');` and then `window.open = mySpy`

Comment: if  I use this, I am getting error like 
`Expected spy on open to be 'link' `

Answer (score 4):

In new version of jasmine(3.5) above solution is not working. I found some work around to fix new window open while running test cases. Add below line of code before calling your `window.open(url,_blank);`

```
 window.open = function () { return window; }
```