# Fixing error: not implemented: window.open during angular testing

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-test

I'm currently tests for an angular app I'm working on and im running into difficultly testing a function which will simply open up a new window to an external site. When I run tests on my function, I get an error

Error: Not implemented: window.open

Below is some code, the first line is where I'm getting the error

```
const blankWindow = window.open('', _blank);
blankWindow.location.href = externalSiteUrl
```

How do I fix this function to ensure I don't get this error? Is there another way to test opening a window in a new location to avoid this issue althogether?

Thanks

Comment: Testing, means jasmine ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jasmine.js Testing - spy on window.open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39603419/jasmine-js-testing-spy-on-window-open)

Answer (score 2):

You should spy on the `window.open` in your test.

```
 const windowOpenSpy = spyOn(window, 'open');
```

and you can verify if it was called from your method or by your actions:

```
expect(windowOpenSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(externalSiteUrl);
```

Update:  If you want to test that `open` has been run then you would do:

```
spyOn(window, 'open').and.callThrough()

...

expect(window.open).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

The `.and.callThrough()` is really important. If you don't use it then the normal `open` will be replaced with a **dummy/mock** function which does nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One other problem this is arising is now, when I run the function which calls the above two lines (from my question), I'm getting an error, cannot read location of undefined. Do you have any idea why this might be?

Comment: That is because you are trying to set the `href` `blankWindow.location.href`