# How can I unit test if certain website has been opened using Karma - Jasmine?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a list of components, some of them come with the property "factor" and others comes with the property "quickpay".

I created a couple getters for them:

```
get hasFactor(): boolean {
    return this.load.factor;
}
get hasQuickpay(): boolean {
    return this.load.quickpay;
}
```

and then created a function that among other things opens a certain URL depending on if "factor" or "quickpay" is `true` (if one of them is `true` the other is `false`).

```
visitPage(){
    if(this.hasFactor){
        this.trackLink(SearchSharedTracking.goToFactor,this.Factor);
        window.open('https://www.spacepln.com/factor/ ','_blank');
    }else{
        this.trackLink(SearchSharedTracking.goToQuickpay,this.Quickpay);
        window.open('https://www.spacepln.com/quickpay','_blank');
    }
}
```

In my .spect file, I have to test using Karma - Jasmine whether the factor page was opened or quickpay was opened. I'm stuck and don't know how to write a unit test for that.

Comment: Possible solution can be find here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39603419/jasmine-js-testing-spy-on-window-open

Answer (score 1):

You can spy on window.open to test which URL gets opened according to your specified conditions. These tests should work.

```
    it('shout open factor page', () => {
        spyOn(window, 'open');
        component.hasFactor = true;
        visitPage(false);        
        expect(window.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith('https://www.spacepln.com/factor/','_blank')
    });

    
    it('shout open quickpay page', () => {
        spyOn(window, 'open');
        component.hasFactor = false;
        visitPage(false);        
        expect(window.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith('https://www.spacepln.com/quickpay','_blank')
    });
```

Comment: I throws me error that I can not assign "true" or "false" to hasFactor here: component.hasFactor = false;
since it is a read-only property. Maybe because it is a getter? How could I work around this? thanks.

Comment: You can spy on your getter functions and return a custom value like this - spyOn(component, 'hasFactor').and.returnValue(true);